# How to write into influxdb using line Protocol with Python

Tags: python, influxdb

I am using line protocol and Python to write into InfluxDB. Below is the code that creates DB and working fine.

```
 client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
    print("Creating database: " + dbname)
    client.create_database(dbname)
    print("Database created: " + dbname)
```

I want to write below mention sample data using Line protocol into influxDB

Sample lines of data of Line protocol looks like

```
interface,path=address,element=link value=3
interface,path=address,element=link value=7
interface,path=address,element=link value=4
```

I am using latest version of InfluxDB which supports line protocol.

Any idea about how the client.write statement looks like for python client?

Comment: In Java i can do this easily  influxDB.write(dbName, "default",InfluxDB.ConsistencyLevel.ALL,"interface,path=address,element=link value=4"); I need the same in python

Comment: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use line protocol from python3 to insert data.

```
    >>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient 
    >>> client = InfluxDBClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=8086, username='admin', password='password', ssl=False, verify_ssl=False)
    >>> client.write(['interface,path=address,elementss=link value=3'],{'db':'yourdb'},204,'line')
```